# Best Practices - Disabling/Avoiding Content Copying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, testing

Well guys, I am working on a test system for my site, and I assume that people will probably try to copy my questions and search them on google, or may be print the screen to study the question after the test.

These are the possible ways to copy info: 
1) By pressing the PrintScreen key;
2) By pressing the keys combination: Alt + PrintScreen;
 
3) By pressing the right mouse, clicking on copy;
4) By pressing the keys combination: Control + C;
5) By using print tools, like fraps, or ms snipping tool;

So how can i force the user to close all programs, and prevent him from using the methods above listed? Probably Javascript, or Jquery, but how?

Comment: Neither of protection method will really work, so just stop annoying your users.

Comment: absolutely pointless. there is 'always' another work around. You'll just tick people off, invest time and money trying to stop them, and in the end, get no where.

Comment: You can not. Since JavaScript runs on client-side, it can be manipulated by the user. For example, they could simply disable JavaScript in their browser. Or they could run scripts which disable your attempts to temper with their programs and key combinations.

Comment: Also anyone with a good memory can memorize the questions, rendering this effort pointless anyway.

Comment: Users can also view the page source, or inspect the DOM with developer tools and copy the question from *there*, and can in any case look at your page and retype the questions in another browser window.

Comment: .... and then there's always the camera I can hold in front of the screen and make a picture. This is why organizations that do online tests but want to safeguard their test questions (like http://Toefl.org) conduct tests only in controlled environments where they have somebody watching every participant

Comment: If you spend as much money as the RIAA does (hint: millions of dollars) you can expect results as good as theirs (hint: thepiratebay).

Comment: All that said, though, there is one straightforward way to make a question at least inaccessible to copy+paste: render it in an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual solution that works to stop people from copying stuff, as other people said.  In addition, if you force the ALT key to stop working, then people with disabilities will no longer be able to use your page.  So I would do something completely different: whenever stuff you don't want to happen occurs, make it impossible to read your page (unless the person taking the test knows how to use developer tools in their browser).

If we assume this is your CSS styling:

```
body { 
    user-select:none;  /* try to prevent highlighting of text */
}
.readable {     /* readable = contrasting colors */
     color:black;
     background-color:white;
}
.unreadable {    /* unreadable = the same color */
     color:white;
     background-color:white;
}
.unreadable::selection {     /* for highlighted text, if user-select fails */
     background-color:white;
     color:white;
}
```

Then here is a basic readability-changing function:

```
function canYouReadMe(yes) {
    if(yes) {  //we can read black on white
        document.body.setAttribute('class','readable');
    } else {   //we can't read white on white
        document.body.setAttribute('class','unreadable');
    }
}
```

Here is JQuery for handling control, print screen, and alt.  Key goes down, you can't read the page.  Key goes up, you can read it again.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey              //control key
           || e.keyCode == 44  //print screen
           || e.keyCode == 18  //alt key
      ) {
        canYouReadMe(false);
        if(e.ctrlKey) {
           e.preventDefault();  //stop copy-paste but not alt
           return false;
        }
    }
});
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey              //control key
           || e.keyCode == 44  //print screen
           || e.keyCode == 18  //alt key
      ) {
        canYouReadMe(true);
        if(e.ctrlKey) {
           e.preventDefault(); 
           return false;
        }
    }
});
```

And another that handles the right mouse button (which is number 3):

```
$(window).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 3) { 
        canYouReadMe(false);
        e.preventDefault();  //stop the menu from appearing
        return false;
    }
});
$(window).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 3) { 
        canYouReadMe(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

And here is what you need for stopping other programs and non-focus printscreen: your page will be unreadable unless it's in focus.  So, if they change to another window, they won't be able to see anything.  This prevents them from simply reading your page while typing in another window, too.

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    canYouReadMe(true);  //read on focus
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    canYouReadMe(false);  //unreadable when focus is lost
});
```

If window focus/blur fails, you might also look into using CSS that will render things only readable when in full-screen.  I am not sure if that is doable or not.

I have not tested any of this -- it is just my theory that it should work, with a few tweaks here and there.

EDIT: To address the people talking about view source etc.: You should use ajax to render your text.  That way, if they disable JavaScript, they'll see nothing, and if they use view source, they'll still see nothing.  Again, they can get around it with developer tools (e.g. Inspect Element), but if they're that savvy, you're not stopping them, anyway.

Comment: It is true, as mentioned, that no solution is perfect. But this, along with setting the @media-print to display:none !important in the page's CSS helps to prevent printing of a page. And there are special versions of JS PDF libraries that will help block other cursor actions. 
Stopping 'snipping' is another option; I haven't tried the above suggestions, but they seem worthwhile. So, an upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

As all the previous posters have stated, there is no way to prevent users from any of those actions.

However you could disable text selection via css and make it a little more "inconvenient" and could discourage your normal every day user from copy+pasting so easily.  Of course a savvy user can even bypass this, so it's not fool proof either.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no technological solution, it's either too hard or unfeasible.

What traditional methods do teachers have to mitigate the use copying? Make multiple versions. Change some variables, have a different outcome.

Maybe you have better ideas?